# Unsorted segment argmax workaround tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create a `tf_boolean_mask` that filters duplicate indices from a tensor, by the value of the indices. If the value is greater than that of a duplicate it should be kept, the others discarded. If index and value are identical, only one should remain:

```
[Pseudocode]
for index in indices
    If index is unique:
        keep index = True
    else:
        if val[index] > val[index of all other duplicate indices]:
            keep index = True
        elif val[index] < val[index of any other duplicate indices]:
            keep index = False
        elif val[index] == val[index of any other duplicate indices]:
            keep only a single one of the equal indices(doesn't matter which)
```

A short example for the problem is the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

index = tf.convert_to_tensor([  10,    5,   20,    20,    30,    30])
value = tf.convert_to_tensor([  1.,   0.,   2.,    0.,    0.,    0.])
# bool_mask =                [True, True, True, False,  True, False]
# or                         [True, True, True, False, False,  True]
# the index 3 is filtered because index 2 has a greater value (2 comp. to 0)
# The index 4 and 5 are identical in their respective values, that's why both
# of them can be kept, but at maximum one of them. 


...
bool_mask = ?
```

My current approach succesfully solves the removal of duplicates with different values but fails at the ones with identical value. However this is an edge case that unfortunately appears in my data:

```
import tensorflow as tf

y, idx = tf.unique(index) 
num_segments = tf.shape(y)[0]
maximum_vals = tf.unsorted_segment_max(value, idx, num_segments)

fused_filt = tf.stack([tf.cast(y, tf.float32), maximum_vals],axis=1)
fused_orig = tf.stack([tf.cast(index, tf.float32), value], axis=1)

fused_orig_tiled = tf.tile(fused_orig, [1, tf.shape(fused_filt)[0]])
fused_orig_res = tf.reshape(fused_orig_tiled, [-1, tf.shape(fused_filt)[0], 2])

comp_1 = tf.equal(fused_orig_res, fused_filt)
comp_2 = tf.reduce_all(comp_1, -1)
comp_3 = tf.reduce_any(comp_2, -1)
# comp_3 = [True, True, True, False, True, True]
```

A pure tensorflow solution would be nice, since a For loop over the indices could be implemented rather simply. Thank you.